# Flask not working with pyaudio

Tags: python, html, linux, flask, pyaudio

I'm having a problem using pyaudio with Flask. The code for the flask app is as follows:

```
from importlib import import_module
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import pyaudio
import wave

app = Flask(__name__)

def generateAudio():
    CHUNK = 2048 #1024
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 1
    RATE = 48000
    RECORD_SECONDS = 1
    p1 = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    streamIn = p1.open(format=FORMAT,
            channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
            input_device_index=2)

    for i in range(0, int(RATE/CHUNK*RECORD_SECONDS)):
            data  = streamIn.read(CHUNK, exception_on_overflow = False)
            yield bytes(data)

@app.route("/audio_feed")
def audio_feed():
    return Response(generateAudio(), mimetype="audio/x-wav;codec=pcm")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='x', threaded=True,port=x)
```

It seems that the Python script is yielding data correctly, but the sound just doesn't play. There is no error output from Flask, it runs as if it was playing it normally.

In the HTML I just use the native `<audio>` tag to play from the audio_feed url. It works when I'm playing a wav file, but it doesn't work when I'm dynamically reading something from the microphone. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/6wg24z/is_there_any_tutorial_on_how_to_run_pyaudio_with/) helps you. You can't run your Pyaudio code ( which is on the server ) on the visitor's computer without having the user download that Python script, install python, install its dependencies, etc.